# Using a complete sentence after a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know, ***prepositions are followed by a noun or noun phrase or a wh-clause***. But the following  sentence confused me because the author used a complete sentence after the "for".

> But evidently the sound of it pleased Gastby ***for Tom remained "the polo player" for the rest of the evening***.

I don't understand why the author didn't use this form :

> But evidently the sound of it pleased Gastby ***for Tom remaining "the polo player" for the rest of the evening***

Answer (score 2):

Here "for" is not being used as a preposition, it's a [conjunction](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Conjunction) - a synonym for "because".

As that Wiktionary link points out, this usage is quite dated; you wouldn't use it now, but it would have been reasonably common at the time Gatsby was set.

Comment: I think using modern grammar to explain old forms is anachronistic. For here clearly functions as a conjunction.

Comment: Contemporary grammar treats this "for" as a preposition, not a subordinator. Likewise "because".

Comment: Contemporary grammar does not apply to historical usages.

Comment: @Lambie This use of *for* wasn't deemed so historical as to be excluded from Huddleston and Pullum's *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002), where they suggest the preposition analysis is more suitable than the coordinator one for the reasons they provide.

Comment: @userr2684291 Oh yes, the gods of modern grammar. I can't see the reasons but it would not matter anyway. When one substitutes because for for, the sentence immediately becomes obvious. There's no point in even mentioning grammar when the semantic value here is what makes the difference.

Comment: @Lambie If it makes you feel any better, Bas Aarts in *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (2011) classifies such words as "conjunctive prepositions" (a subcategory of prepositions). As far as your second claim goes: the asker themselves has introduced the grammatical viewpoint from which they'd presumably like to receive the answer – they posit that "prepositions are followed by a noun or noun phrase or a wh-clause". I for one consider it valuable to dispel their misapprehensions rather than tacitly agree with them (see BillJ's answer).

Comment: @userr2684291Simpler is better: But evidently the sound of it pleased Gastby ***because*** Tom remained "the polo player" for the rest of the evening. The OP did not understand the meaning of the word for in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> *But evidently the sound of it pleased Gastby for Tom remained "the*
>   *polo player" for the rest of the evening*.

"For" is a preposition, which here has a similar meaning to the prepositions "because" and "since".

Prepositions can take a wide range of complements, not just NPs, but predicatives, PPs, AdvPs and clauses.

In your example, the preposition "for" has the declarative content clause *Tom remained* *the polo player for the rest of the evening* as its complement.

Your suggestion of using "remaining" won't work as it can't satisfy the complement requirements of "for", which in this instance means "because".

Comment: "for Tom remained the polo player for the rest of the evening" does not mean: "Tom remained the polo player for the rest of the evening". The latter is not even in the text. And the meaning is completely different.

Comment: @Lambie That's not what the answer says either; rather, it says *for* takes the quoted clause as complement.